# Difference between string[80] and string in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I am migrating a delphi 7 application to delphi XE4. In Delphi 7, some variables are declared like this:

```
var abc : string[80];
```

While migrating this code, I am changing above code declaration as

```
var abc : string;
```

As per my understanding, string[80] is ansistring and string is unicode. So, is it right way to do it?

I am following the below link from stackoverflow:

[Convert Char into AnsiChar or WideChar (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997142/convert-char-into-ansichar-or-widechar-delphi)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Fixed length string is a sort of [`ShortString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/String_Types#Short_Strings) which is a single byte char type. I'd say for your application will be better to have all the strings in the Unicode form rather than ANSI, so if I were you, I'd use `array[0..79] of Char` or just `string`.

Comment: @TLama - Thanks for clearing my doubt. Also one more question related to it. Shortstring is also used in many placed in delphi 7 code. Should I replace those declarations with string in Delphi XE4?

Comment: Some additional references: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio

Comment: Generally you should use string. But you don't tell us why the old code used shortstring. That's been bad since Delphi 2. What does the code do with these variables? How can we give sound advice without the full picture.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - These varibles have fixed length as per database columns length. I want to maintain the length of string but in unicode way.

Comment: You can use string. I expect that the db layer will truncate the strings so you may need to do nothing more in your code.

Comment: Note that code such as `if abc[1] = 'X' then` is always safe to use with string[80], but may need to be replaced with `if (abc <> '')  and (abc[1] = 'X') then` to avoid access violations when trying to read the first character of an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you are correct:

- `string[#]` are subtypes of `ShortString`.
  It has a maximum of 255 characters (depending on the #), and the encoding is undetermined (i.e. up to you).
- `string` is a regular string, which was single-byte (now called `AnsiString`) up until Delphi 2007, and multi-byte (now called `UnicodeString`) as of Delphi 2009.
  Until Delphi 2007, the encoding is undetermined. As of Delphi 2009, both `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` can have an encoding.

More background information can be found in these two Delphi documentation topics:

- [ShortString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ShortString)
- [AnsiString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString)
- [UnicodeString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString)
- [Delphi String Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_%28Delphi%29)
- [Unicode in RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio)

Answering your question about how you should replace `ShortString`:

It totally depends on how you used your `ShortString` in Delphi 7. Depending on the use, there are multiple ways to go:

- `string`
- arrays of `byte`
- `AnsiString`

That all depends on the kind of data you are storing, so that is the first thing you need to find out.

Comment: Not quite true. string[17] is only 18 bytes in size and can not hold more than 17 AnsiChars and a length byte. Shortstring is in fact the same as string[255]. Otherwise +1.

Comment: There is a crucial difference not mentioned yet: ShortString is a value type whereas String is a reference type -> you cannot use String type as a part of persistent data without additional serialization/deserialization, but ShortString you can. Hence the major criterium is a data usage.